# User specific information upon loin

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc

I am looking to make a website whereby a user will be able to login and register. Once registered and logged in I would like for them to see a list of their own customers and carry out some functionally configured to the user (e.g send an SMS from their registered phone number).

I have seen plenty of tutorials on how to implement both login and register functionality. But I have no idea how to make the information shown be specific to each customer?

Can someone assist by pointing me in the right direction for something like this? Or even a template that may already have it done?

So fair I have been able to create a very basic site (localhost) that has a user login and registration form.

Answer (score 0):

Sending SMS from website is done with paid services, you can search some of them.

User specific website is done for example by using PHP. For example you have form for registration and then save the data into a database. Next time the user comes, you offer him login form, if he logs in succesfuly, you now know who the user is and offer some content according to the user. **For example** (simplified) you will have a folder named "Peter" and in this folder you will have informations about Peters customers. And if Peter logs in, you offer him data from this folder.